# Getting an error in Retrofit Callback implementation

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have written a retrofit callback for retrieving data it is as follows

```
 AppConfig.read api = adapter.create(AppConfig.read.class);
    api.readData(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void success(JsonElement result, Response response) {

            String myResponse = result.toString();
            Log.d("response", "" + myResponse);
            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                int success = jObj.getInt("success");
                if (success == 1) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("details");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        id.add(jo.getString("id"));
                        name.add(jo.getString("name"));
                        age.add(jo.getString("age"));
                        mobile.add(jo.getString("mobile"));
                        email.add(jo.getString("email"));
                        details_list.setAdapter(displayAdapter);
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Details 
                    Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                      Log.d("exception", e.toString());
            }
        }
            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d("Failure", error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(StudReg.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

    }
  );
 }
```

my API interface is as follows

```
   public interface read {
    @GET("/displayAll.php")
    void readData(Callback<JsonElement> callback);
}
```

But i am getting an error that `Class 'anonymous class derived from callback' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'success(T,Response)' in CallBack`

Please help me. thanks a lot

Comment: Add your log file to the question the error in question. This will help in giving a better idea to readers.

Comment: you have implemented wrong.  
please check below article https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html. More i guess your getting confused volley not sure on my last statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the following code, as you are instating a generic class.
Change this statement declaration
`api.readData(new Callback())`
to

```
api.readData(new Callback<JsonElement>()) <br/>
```

as you have defined in interface that 
readData method will take parameter of generic class

```
Callback<JsonElement>
```

which i can find from your interface  declaration here,

```
void readData(Callback<JsonElement> callback);
```

Thats the reason the compiler seems to be complaining